# Deconvolution (polynomial division) in R

Tags: r, polynomial-math, deconvolution

I need to perform a deconvolution of two vectors. This is equivalent to polynomial division. For example, in Matlab I would use [deconv](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deconv.html) function. Is there a similar/equivalent function in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deconvolution with R (decon and deamer package)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462919/deconvolution-with-r-decon-and-deamer-package)

Comment: Jason, even though the titles are similar, this is completely different question from the one you quoted. The termin Deconvolution refers there to something completely unrelated to Deconvolution in my question and so are the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `deconv` in package `pracma`

```
c = c(10, 40, 100, 160, 170, 120)
u = c(1, 2, 3, 4)

#install.packages("pracma")
library(pracma)
deconv(c, u)
#$q
#[1] 10 20 30

#$r
#[1] 0 0 0
```